# Postgres sum by distinct values in join table

Tags: sql, postgresql

### Problem

I'm trying to construct a query for a report. I'm using Postgres 9.6.1. Below I've described my schema, some same data, and the result I'm trying to achieve.

Apologies for the odd table schema. I'm starting with a join table of AlertPost, and essentially for each Alert (by `alert_id`) I need the sum of followers for *distinct* users. The `user_follow_count` is denormalized to the Post table for other speed reasons in the application, which is why it's shown on the User table here.

I've already tried a ton of queries with group by, windowing and distinct, but I'm not getting the right answers.

### Schema

Assume both tables are somewhat large (10mm+ rows) and all foreign keys are indexed.

Table 1: Post

```
- id
- user_id
- user_follow_count
```

Table 2: AlertPost

```
- id
- alert_id (different from id, this is a join table)
- post_id
```

Goal: For each alert_id, what is the sum of the user_follower_count for each distinct user?

### Example data

```
AlertPosts
id: 1, alert_id: 1, post_id: 1 # Same alert_id, two different post_ids
id: 2, alert_id: 1, post_id: 2
id: 3, alert_id: 2, post_id: 3
id: 4, alert_id: 2, post_id: 4


Post
id: 1, user_id: 1, user_follow_count: 3 # Same user between several posts
id: 2, user_id: 2, user_follow_count: 5
id: 3, user_id: 1, user_follow_count: 3
id: 4, user_id: 1, user_follow_count: 3
```

### Desired results

```
AlertPosts:
alert_id: 1, unique_followers: 8 # (sum of user_follow_count from user_id 1, 2)
alert_id: 2, unique_followers: 3 # (there are only posts from user_id 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it with two steps. First, you must distinct the combination of `alert_id`, `user_id` and `user_follow_count` and only then sum the result.

```
--Creating samples...
CREATE TABLE alert_posts (id, alert_id, post_id) AS
    VALUES 
        (1,1,1),
        (2,1,2),
        (3,2,3),
        (4,2,4);

CREATE TABLE post (id, user_id, user_follow_count) AS
    VALUES 
        (1,1,3),
        (2,2,5),
        (3,1,3),
        (4,1,3); 

--First step: flattening result
WITH tmp AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
            a.alert_id,
            --Assuming last_value to get user_follow_count of repeated users
            last_value(p.user_follow_count) OVER (
                    PARTITION BY 
                            a.alert_id, 
                            p.user_id 
                    ORDER BY p.id DESC) AS user_follow_count 
    FROM 
            alert_posts a
    JOIN post p ON p.id = a.post_id
)
--Now you can do a regular sum 
SELECT alert_id, SUM(user_follow_count) AS unique_followers FROM tmp GROUP BY alert_id;
```

Test [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c07b4/16).

Comment: I should check my indices; because the subselect itself even is taking approximately forever (several minutes now) to return a result, even with a limit of 10 on my staging database.

It seems to require a seq scan on both tables. Alert_posts is a few million entries, and posts is maybe 30mm right now.

Comment: What's the output of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`?

Comment: Limit  (cost=27796596.40..27796604.81 rows=10 width=20)
  ->  Unique  (cost=27796596.40..28204705.37 rows=485268 width=20)
        ->  Sort  (cost=27796596.40..27932632.73 rows=54414529 width=20)
              Sort Key: a.alert_id, (last_value(p.followed_by_count) OVER (?))
              ->  WindowAgg  (cost=16232907.81..17457234.72 rows=54414529 width=20)
                    ->  Sort  (cost=16232907.81..16368944.14 rows=54414529 width=20)
                          Sort Key: a.alert_id, p.nuid, p.id DESC

Comment: ->  Hash Join  (cost=2589700.97..5893546.13 rows=54414529 width=20)
                                Hash Cond: (a.interaction_id = p.id)
                                ->  Seq Scan on alert_interactions a  (cost=0.00..1179822.29 rows=54414529 width=8)
                                ->  Hash  (cost=2353057.43..2353057.43 rows=13613643 width=16)
                                      ->  Seq Scan on interactions p  (cost=0.00..2353057.43 rows=13613643 width=16)

Comment: I could only get an EXPLAIN since the ANALYZE never finishes. Posts == interactions and alert_posts == alert_interactions.

Comment: Ah, I was forgetting to constrain my venues and time (not in the original problem). This brought the set of values down to something pretty small. Your solution works. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help you @tibbon